Linear Combination of matrices by eigenvalues of shared eigenvector gives projection into the space of that eigenvector
I'm trying to understand why a particular method in representation theory as applied to inorganic chemistry, called the Projection Operator Method, works - it seems a bit magical, but what it's doing is straightforward enough to at least describe. In short:
We have a group $R$ of $n \times n$ invertible matrices, so named because they are a representation of a (finite) group $G$ - that is, there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $R$. In the simple case (which is all I care about for now), I will say the representation $R$ is reducible into a direct sum of 1-dimensional subrepresentations; in other words, the action of $R$ on $\mathbb R^n$ can be described as the direct sum of its action on 1-dimensional $R$-invariant subspaces, e.g. action on shared eigenvectors of all elements of $R$. In chemistry, we are given the precomputed "$1 \times 1$ matrices" (numbers) corresponding to each 1d subspace, in the form of a character table. Since the 1d subspaces are shared eigenvectors of $R$, these numbers are the eigenvalues corresponding to the eigenvector that forms the subspace, one for each matrix in $R$.
Then, the method itself: Our goal is to find the shared eigenvectors (or eigenspaces in the case of degenerate eigenvalues) of $R$. Given a set of matrices $R$ and the character table corresponding to $G$, we can fairly straightforwardly find one of these 1d "factors" of $R$ in the table, so we can know the eigenvalues for that particular representation without knowing the eigenvector a priori (again, why you are able to do this is beyond me, especially because the table has a fixed number of 1d reps that can be used to construct any of the >1d representations of $G$, but the important thing for now is that it does). The projection operator then says the following: pick the eigenvalues corresponding to one of the shared eigenvectors of $R$. For each matrix in $R$, multiply by the corresponding eigenvalue and sum the matrices. The resulting linear combination will produce a matrix that projects onto the space of eigenvectors which have the eigenvalues for each matrix as used in the linear combination.
This fact is only supported by A) this method is in inorganic chemistry textbooks (but never explained nor proven) and has been used effectively for decades and B) experimental evidence that yeah this holds up every time I've tested it.
Thus, my question: why.
